# Why has pip/python/pyinstaller started throwing errors?

Tags: python, cmd, pip

I'm not sure if this is the right site to be asking this on, so sorry if it's a little off topic.

Anyway, for some reason, the `pip` and `python` commands have both stopped working in the Command prompt, as well as `pyinstaller` and are throwing `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` error. They were working fine earlier, so I have no idea why they suddenly stopped working. I did not update my python version, but now `py` works instead of `python`. I have installed a few modules today, *using pip*, but I don't know why that would affect them. I can still run python files.

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: It appears as if your `Scripts` folder is for some reason no longer in `PATH`. You can simply it back.

Comment: Never mind that, got it working. Thanks!